# append multiple div

Tags: random, append, bind

I want to add multiple circles to the `body` and bind a function so that each circle will do a random move on click. I already tried something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/375/

```
$(function() {
$('.button1').click(function(){
    $('body').append('<div class="circles"> </div>')
    .bind('click',function() {
        var h = $('body').height()-100;
        var w = $('body').width()-100;

        var movh = Math.floor( Math.random() * h);
        var movw = Math.floor( Math.random() * w);
    $(this).animate({
     top: movh,
     left: movw
    }, 1000);
});
});
});
```

`$(this)` gets the body, but how can I get the appended div each time? when I bind the `$(.circles)` class, all circles will be moved.

Comment: when you call `$(.circles)` it's going to get ALL the elements with the class `circles`. Perhaps you can store it in an array and choose a random index to move? or iteratively go through each one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different classes for different circles or you can identify your circles by id:
div id="circle1"/ div id="circle2" / etc.

Have you ever tried this: http://d3js.org/ ? It's a very powerful library. D3 "Three circles tutorial: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html

Comment: That would make to many divs.I try to keep it simple. Thanks for the d3js tip!